# Validating a string in a file

Tags: java

I was given an assignment to read a .txt file from Java. The file contains something as follow:

> ID:SampleID
>
> Job:Manager
>
> Name:Samuel Rahul

The read is successful, and I was able to print the file content. I'm using Scanner to read the file:

```
FileReader _reader = new FileReader(_name);
            BufferedReader _br = new BufferedReader(_reader);


            while((line = _br.readLine()) != null) {

                System.out.println(line);
            }
```

The problem is, I need to validate, for example, that the ID is not empty such as,

> ID:

If the ID is empty, an error will show up. I was expected to use 'delimiter' for the task.

Edit :

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(line).useDelimiter("ID:\\s*");

                System.out.println(s.next())
```

I have used .useDelimiter, but the problem is, it shows the rest of the text such as Job and Name, which could be misguided as an "ID", and then the value of ID is always not empty.

I want the exact String after ":"(which I got, except that it also include the whole String after that, including Job:Manager and Name:Samuel Rahul) next to ID. This what confuses me, so that I can validate if the ID String is null or not.

If I can get the exact String after "ID:" and excluding their next line, then I can validate the value. I think my regex is wrong, but I couldn't find what.

Comment: You can use a [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) for that.

Comment: you could split the `line` by `:` and check if `splittet.length > 1 && splittet[1] != null && !splittet[1].trim().equals("")`.

Comment: I have edited the question. I used .useDelimiter to see what will be printed, but it just shows the rest of String until "Rahul".

Is there a way so that it does not include String from the next line?

Comment: As far as the examples go, Scanner (Pattern) might be a bit overkill for that, actually.

Comment: @TheLima If you have a workaround for this, I'm happy to try it. 

This is part of my assignment requirement(validate the ID, so if the ID field is empty, returns an error), and I'm learning something new from this.

Comment: Your `BufferedReader` is already capable of reading lines. Use the `.readLine()` method within a `while-loop` with conditional `.ready()` --- Unless you want to use the Scanner's internal `Pattern` to solve the parsing too; in which case, given the level of your assignment, I think you'd be *"trying to run before learning how to walk"*.

Comment: @TheLime I've read on the BufferedReader .readLine(), I manage to print the line, but it prints its whole considering that there's no "\n" found in the .txt file.

As .readLine() searches for "\n" or "\r", I believe putting this in a txt file is not comprehensive. How to settle on this one.

Comment: `readLine()` should find both Windows (/r/n), Unix-like (/n), and even other  line separators without problems...You usually don't need to worry about which is being used by the file...If it's misbehaving for you, you might be running into a separate, unrelated problem here.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it will below code:

```
        String id="ID:SampleID";
        String arr[] = id.split(":");
        String key=arr[0];
        String value=arr[1];

        if (value != null && "".equals(value.trim())){
            System.out.println("ALL IS PERFECT!!");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("RAISE ERROR!!");
        }
```

Comment: Giving solutions away instead of teaching programming practices...Not cool.

Comment: I didn't say the solution won't work. I said giving the solution away is not a welcome approach when the OP clearly states it's an assignment...for which he is supposed to be the one facing the problem and coming up with a solution.

Comment: You need to know that I'm using scanner to read the txt file, and I'm not using static id="ID:SampleID". 

Because, the value might change, if let say the user change the ID from txt, not from source code. I understand your code a bit, but the problem start when (a) I want to get the exact String after ID from the txt and (b)how I can validate on that point.

I've edited the question.

Comment: I know string i gave is static, and its only for your understanding, all you have to do is put my code in your `while((line = _br.readLine()) != null) {}` loop, according to `ID:*` line it will work fine, you have to put extra if else loop to check ID, job & name field, hope you got it!!

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an assignment, I won't give a solution, but rather try to teach you what you need to learn in order to solve the problem yourself.

## The problem:

1. You need to be able to read the file and extract it's contents.

   - You've already achieved that; although, based on your example, `Scanner` might be overkill.
2. You need to separate your *properties* (identifiers) from their *values*.

   - This is commonly called ***parsing***; so you need to *parse* the file/content.
   - The pattern to separate property from value in your example is well-defined and extremely easy: In any given `line`, content *before* the `:` character is `property`, and content *after* the `:` character is `value`.
3. As of your assignment, you need to check if your `property` called `ID` has a `value`, or in other words, that it's `value` isn't `empty`.

---

## How to solve:

1. For your assignment, a more appropriate solution is probably to use the `BufferedReader.readLine()` method within a `while(BufferedReader.ready())` loop.

---

2. There are many ways to solve parsing:

***Solution 1***

- `String.indexOf(char)` with the `':'` char.
  or...
- `String.indexOf(String)` with the `":"` string.
  combined with...
- `String.substring(int begin, int end)`

***Solution 2***

- `String.split(String pattern)` with `":"` pattern, where `result[0]` would be the `property` and `result[1]` would be the `value`.

***Solution 3***

- Using a `Pattern` & `Matcher` structure; in which case the `Scanner` you're using already has a `Pattern` built-in, which could be reused; but this is probably getting a little ahead of the intent of your assignment.

***Other solutions***

- Many other solutions are possible.

---

3. Knowing if the value is empty (or, `null` in other similar cases), after you've *parsed* it from the property identifier, is easy enough:

   - `String.isEmpty()` or, more tolerant to strings containing only white-space characters, `String.trim().isEmpty()`

Comment: I only need to understand now(I'm more of understanding problem kinda person), well your 'guide' is helpful to me. I've achieved the first one, although I do think I need to find another workaround of that, since I believe that's the major problem.